# delete image in folder and his ''mini'' size in same time

Tags: php, image, delete-file

I've made a folder "../img/travaux/villa" that contain my image, so when i upload image i made a script that create a "mini" copy of this image inside a new folder "../img/travaux/villa/mini", with the same name.

now i want make a button for delete my image, but i also want that delete the "mini" image in the same time how can i make it ?

this is my code for show and delete the image, but that doesn't delete the mini image:

```html
<?php
if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
    $filename = $_POST['delete_file'];
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        unlink($filename);
        echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
    }
}
$folder = glob("../img/travaux/villa/*jpg");
foreach ($folder as $picture) {
    echo "<div class='divimages'>"; 
    echo '<img src="'.$picture.'"/>';
    echo '<form method="post">';
 echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$picture.'" name="delete_file" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" class="delete-button" value="Delete image" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo "</div>";  
}
?>
```

Comment: on line 4, instead of unlink($filename); type echo $filename. see what's coming and if it actually goes inside that if (), might be file path issue. you can build path using __DIR__ , or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], or other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line of code after unlink main image:

```
unlink(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_DIRNAME).'/mini/'.pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$fileName = basename($_POST['delete_file']);
// this will remove the path and leave only the name of the file.
$filePath = 'your full path'.'/'.$fileName;
// now build the 'mini image' full path - like '/var/www/project/img/travaux/villa/mini'.'/'.$fileName
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    unlink($filePath);
    echo 'File '.$filePath.' has been deleted';
} else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filePath.', file does not exist';
}
```

Note: this only deletes the 'mini' image. You'll need to add this to your existing code to also delete the main image

Answer (score 0):

You should create a simple file remover function which takes an array of file names. And call the function with booth names. This is a flexible solution, because the changing parts takes place outside.

Answer (score 0):

There is a vulnerability in your code, someone can delete any file from your website root folder, be careful!

You can try the following code:

```
$paths = array(
    'orig' => '../img/travaux/villa/',
    'mini' => '../img/travaux/villa/mini/',
);

if (array_key_exists('delete_file', $_POST)) {
    $filename = basename($_POST['delete_file']);
    foreach($paths as $path) {
        if (file_exists($path.$filename)) {
            if(!unlink($path.$filename)) {
                $error = 'File '.$filename.' could not be deleted';
            }
            else {
                echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
            }
        }
        else {
            $error = 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
        }
        if($error) echo $error;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually access to this page require a password